# When Using Taylor Expansion for a Simple Function is a better way to compute?

Tags: numerical-limitations

Let's say that we have the function

$$f(x) = 1- \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}{1 + x^2/2}$$

for small $x$.

What I am asking is the following:

I am going to solve this function numerically for $10^{-10}<x<1$. **To have the best precision**, **should I use the function $f(x)$ as it is and make the computer solve it or should I expand the function using Taylor series?** 
In other words:

Since computers use certain arithmetics (64-bit double-precision etc.) it can only contain some of the digits and there will always be an error (loss of precision). What I am trying to understand is can avoid it (not entirely of course) using Taylor series.
if yes;
To what order should I expand it so that computer can store that kind of numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this function numerically"?

Comment: I mean I am going to plot the function for $10^{-10}<x<1$ using let's say Matlab.

Comment: I don't see why evaluating that function would be troublesome for that interval.

Comment: It's not a specific interval. I just wanted to say that x is small and I need numbers with less error. Since computers use certain arithmetics (64-bit double-precision etc.) it can only contain some of the digits and there will always be an error (loss of precision).  What I am trying to understand is can avoid it (not entirely of course) using Taylor series.

Comment: That's not what you ask in your OP, I think that you should correct it accordingly. Furthermore, numerical software is written with this kind of things in mind, I doubt that you can just get better results using a naive approach.

Comment: @Ekrem Can you clarify how much *accuracy* you need? "Plotting" suggests you only need *absolute* accuracy around $10^{-4}$. This computation has issues with subtractive cancellation (as is seen already by looking at $x=1$), so achieving accuracy in line with any chosen floating-point format's precision ("machine accuracy") will be difficult to achieve with *both* the original formula and the Taylor series expansion.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you. I updated the question.

Comment: @njuffa Actually, I don't need a specific accuracy. I just want to know can I make my code better using Taylor series. Also, to what order the expansion can make the result better. If I am not wrong $10^{-16}$ is the limit.

Comment: @njuffa, it seems that the OP is not interested in the behavior close to 1, but to 0.

Comment: @nicoguaro Since we are talking about Taylor series, yes I am interested in small $x$ values. But I think what njuffa trying to say is we can already see the error due to subtraction for around $x=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we want to approximate $$f(x) := 1 - \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$ on $[10^{-10}, 1]$ as accurately as possible, and in particular with an accuracy close to the machine precision associated with a given [IEEE-754 floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format, neither naive computation nor a Taylor series expansion seem suitable. There is an issue with [subtractive cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) that is particular severe for small arguments. We can certainly expand $f(x)$ around $0$, e.g. with the help of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+1+-+%28sqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281%2B%28x%5E2%29%2F2%29%29+): $$\frac{x^{4}}{8}-\frac{x^{6}}{8}+\frac{13x^{8}}{128}-\frac{5x^{10}}{64}+\frac{61x^{12}}{1024}+\mathcal{O}(x^{13})$$

While this would allow us to accurately compute $f(x)$ for arguments very small in magnitude, it is not practical for $x$ near $1$. And since $f(1) \approx 0.0572$, it is easy to see that we encounter the subtractive cancellation issue even there when using the naive approach. Sure enough, a quick experiment shows that the naive computation leads to errors in excess of $256$ [ulps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, meaning the least significant $8$ bits of results for that interval cannot be relied upon.

```c
#include <math.h> // for sqrt()

double func_naive (double x)
{
    return 1.0 - sqrt (1.0 + x * x) / (1.0 + x * x / 2);
}
```

I briefly examined whether we can somehow use the function `sqrt1pm1`, which accurately computes $\sqrt{x + 1}-1$, to minimize the impact from subtractive cancellation, but I couldn't find a way to do this. **Update Nov. 2023 :** The application of `sqrt1pm1` is trivial, as now shown at the end of this answer.

Intuition indicates that if we want to generate results small in magnitude from arguments large in magnitude in a numerically stable fashion, we could use computation based on division. There are various ways to do this. Given that here we are dealing with fixed-precision IEEE-754 floating-point formats and a specific, fairly narrow interval, a rational [minimax approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm) seems to be the best approach. A rational approximation is basically the ratio of two polynomials, i.e. $r(x) = p(x) / q(x)$. A numerically robust way of evaluating each polynomial is [Horner's scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Software like Mathematica or Maple can be used to find such approximations, or one could build one's own tool based on the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). I chose the latter approach here. On platforms with hardware and software support for fused multiply-add ([FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add)) we can use it to achieve a slightly more accurate computation.

Based on testing with 100M random arguments in $[10^{-10}, 1]$ with IEEE-754 `binary64` (double precision) computation, maximum errors around $5$ ulps are observed, which seems reasonable for this quickly constructed code. With careful tweaking of the coefficients the maximum error could likely be reduced a bit further.

```c
#include <math.h> // for fma()

#if HAVE_FMA
#define FMAD(a,b,c) fma(a,b,c)
#else
#define FMAD(a,b,c) (a*b+c)
#endif // HAVE_FMA

// Accurately compute 1-sqrt(1+x*x)/(1+x*x/2) on [1e-10, 1]
// HAVE_FMA=1: max ulp=4.55664 @ x=2.2644149793184315e-6; max rel err=6.36228e-16 @ x=3.5041674402633207e-4
// HAVE_FMA=0: max ulp=5.62062 @ x=6.4687640650198819e-1; max rel err=6.82920e-16 @ x=8.2367484833186755e-1
double func_rat_approx (double x)
{
    double p, q;
    double x2 = x * x;

    p =              - 3.2490268983475442E-5;
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 2.2558281208246997E-3);
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 7.9333170773742845E-1);
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 1.1376929119278506E+1);
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 4.8037227288592518E+1);
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 7.1940878446934676E+1);
    p = FMAD (p, x2, + 3.4917444046359641E+1);

    q =          x2  + 2.2273111565876125E+1;
    q = FMAD (q, x2, + 1.6832675743004904E+2);
    q = FMAD (q, x2, + 5.8322456893291758E+2);
    q = FMAD (q, x2, + 1.0122010119537713E+3);
    q = FMAD (q, x2, + 8.5486657994635436E+2);
    q = FMAD (q, x2, + 2.7933955237087713E+2);

    return (p / q) * x2 * x2;
}
```

I noticed belatedly that `sqrt1pm1()` is actually trivially applicable to the computation of $f(x)$, because $f(x) = -\left(\sqrt{y + 1} - 1\right)$, where $y =\frac{-x^4}{(x^2+2)^2}$. In computational environments that do not provide `sqrtp1pm1` it can be robustly implemented as $\mathrm{sqrt1pm1} (x) := \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$. This results in the following implementation with a maximum observed error (based on 100M test vectors) of about 5 ulps:

```c
// Accurately compute sqrt (x + 1) - 1. Maximum error about 2.25 ulp.
double sqrt1pm1 (double x)
{
    return x / (1 + sqrt (x + 1));
}

// Accurately compute 1-sqrt(1+x*x)/(1+x*x/2) on [1e-10, 1]
// max ulp=5.04575 @ x=1.7814984806121276e-1; max rel err=6.84429e-16 @ x=8.9168378991700131e-2
double func_sqrtp1m1 (double x)
{
    double x2 = x * x;
    double y = -(x2 * x2) / ((x2 + 4) * x2 + 4); // -x**4 / ((x**2 + 2)**2)
    return (- sqrt1pm1 (y));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Could you briefly explain the code? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @Ekrem: I'd be happy to improve the answer if you could you briefly explain what part of the code is unclear. A rational approximation is the ratio of two polynomials: $r(x) =p(x)/q(x)$. Here, both polynomials are evaluated using the Horner scheme.

Comment: I don't know much c++. In fact, I know coding only at a basic level. I searched about this fma() function but I couldn't understand why did you use it. I kind of understood the math behind the Horner scheme but I don't see how you define $p$ and $q$ i.e. where those red numbers come from? Also why the function returns $(p/q) * x^{4}$? Sorry for having so much question. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Ekrem FWIW, the code I posted is C, not C++. The "red numbers" are the coefficients of the polynomials, generated by my proprietary program that generates minimax approximations using the Remez algorithm. You can generate such approximations with widely-used commercial tools like Maple or Mathematica (which I cannot afford and therefore have never used). As to why the approximation takes the form $(p/q)*x^{4}$, see the Taylor series expansion further up in the answer. FMA provides two operations with a *single* rounding and gives some protection against subtractive cancellation; see Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

You can easily approximate $f(x)$ up to fourth order accuracy by using Taylor expansion as:

$$f(x) = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$$

Taylor expansions:

$$\sqrt{1+x^{2}} = 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{x^{4}}{8} + O(x^{5})$$

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}} = 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{4} + O(x^{6})$$

So:

$$f(x) = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}} = 1 - \frac{1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{x^{4}}{8}}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}} - \frac{x^{2}}{2} (\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}}) + \frac{x^{4}}{8}(\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}})$$

or:

$$f(x) = 1 - 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{x^{4}}{4} - \frac{x^{2}}{2}(1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{4}) + \frac{x^{4}}{8}(1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{4}}{8})$$

Now do simplification and eliminate terms that have order of higher than four:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{2} - \frac{x^{4}}{4} - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \frac{x^{4}}{8}$$

So final form is:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{4}}{8} + O(x^{5})$$

Check the results from Wolfram Alpha here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%5Csqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%2F2%29

If you want it up to eighth order accuracy, it's the solution from Wolfram Alpha:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{4}}{8} - \frac{x^{6}}{8} + \frac{13 x^{8}}{128} + O(x^{9})$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but what I tried to ask was "If I compute the function numerically for let's say 10^(-10)<x<1, then should I manipulate the function with Taylor series to have a better precision?". I am going to edit the question to be more clear.